# Why do I get "TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function" when trying to render jsx template

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, babeljs

I have the following:

```
// Test.jsx
const TestTemplate = function(){
    return (
        <div>
        ....
        </div>
    )
}
export { TestTemplate };

// Test.js
import { TestTemplate } from "./Test.jsx"; 
class Test extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return TestTemplate.call(this);
    }
}
```

When I try to run a test with this setup, I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function.
```

My Mocha command is `mocha --compilers js:@babel/register src/**/*.spec.js*` Since I am outputing it as a function not sure what to do.

**Update**

Per the answer I tried to change

```
export { TestTemplate };

export TestTemplate;
```

When I do this Babel fails with an `.jsx: Unexpected token (164:27)`. IJ also suggests that there is a "Declaration Expected"

So as I thought that is invalid JS.

Comment: You are importing the `Template` function, but then you are overriding it straight away with a class `Template`.

Comment: Sorry that was an edit issue

Comment: Should be edited to show the right code